# Is it possible to read a variable from coffee script?

Tags: coffeescript, sass

I define in scss file like this.

```
$base1: #362E2B;
$base2: #43452f;
$base3: #ffce58;
```

And in a coffee script like this.

```
$("#menu a").hover(
 -> $(@).css("background","white").css("color","#43452f")
 -> $(@).css("background","#43452f").css("color","#ffce58")
)
```

If possible I avoid to use magic number in coffee script.
Is there way to read scss variables from coffee script?

Comment: Couldn't you define classes in your CSS and just use class names in Coffeescript?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. Can you show me a example?

Comment: instead fiddling with background and color, you could do "addClass('base2-hover')". Actually, for this particular example, do you need code at all? cannot this be done with the CSS :hover pseudo-class?

Comment: Oh, I've totally forgot about css :hover. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. SASS variables reside server-side only, they never reach the client.

Instead of applying styles directly to your elements, you should be toggling **semantic** classes on your elements, and letting CSS do the work of applying specific colours.